# javascript FullCalendar eventClick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to add events and to set the eventClick

I tried to add event then set the eventClick but its not working

```
var calendar = $('#calendar');
calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', allEvents);


calendar.fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function() {
    alert(1);
  }
});

calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

i just noticed if i change the the ID `calendar` into `myCalendar` i dont have the calendar only buttons  **Today** , **<**, **>** , and when i press TODAY its appear and the eventClick work

how to fix it?

Comment: something like this should work `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {alert(1)}`

Comment: @ArunKumar please check again the question , i add something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `eventClick` and other other attributes in `options` something like this:

```
var options = {
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    header: {   
        right: 'today, prev, agendaWeek, month, next'
    },
    eventClick: function() {
        alert(2);
    }
};
```

then, set `$('#calendar').fullCalendar(options)` and add `allEvents` to calendar, according to FullCalendar documentation. Well, firstly you have to initialize the calendar and then adding events to the source, and by doing that you don't need to use `refetchEvents` again.

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(options);
calendar.fullCalendar('addEventSource', allEvents);
```

Complete code can be seen here [FullCalendar events and other options](https://codepen.io/Adeel91/pen/QZvPyL)

Comment: I found where was problem , i have Neon theme where he set it and i don't know why i can't reset the eventClick so i just set on framework the eventClick

But anyway thx, this also helped me )

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + view.name);

    // change the border color just for fun
    $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

  }
});
```

As per the fullcalendar docs this will work for you.